# Product inventory beyond the basics

Tags: database-design, e-commerce

I am trying to start up a project for exploring e-commerce. I am new to this area. I am looking for the following

1. I have been looking for websites on what columns/fields I should be capturing at the database design stage beyond the tutorial/example level without success
2. Can anyone point me out to website/books where the subject of e-commerce is explored in depth beyond the tutorials and examples, specifically, product inventory. I need to understand how SKU is generated for products of different types, is there any template for it. Are there any rules for generating barcode.
3. Are there any databases available as a demo in relation to the above.
4. What sort of domain knowledge is required to work in the area of e-commerce as a software developer.

Comment: Silverston's Data Model Resource Book vols 1,2

Comment: Neil I have had a look at vol1 excerpt from Amazon it looks really promising. How about some websites that you guys use to obtain knowledge, how about the Gurus in the area of e-commerce

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of heavy questions in there, good sir.

**What sort of domain knowledge is required for e-commerce?** 
Security of storing/not storing credit card numbers.
encryption techniques.
Database table design.
Client-Server security issues.
...
Essentially, imagine what would be on an Amazon lead's resume. :)

I found this for you, hopefully it's at least somewhat informative.

[http://www.amazon.com/books/dp/1578203120](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1578203120)
[http://www.amazon.com/E-commerce-Essential-Marketing-Strategies-Practical/dp/0956526209/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_y](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0956526209)

Here is another Stack Overflow link that doesn't say much, but seemed to be helpful to the person asking it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2893709/ecommerce-database-design-looking-for-good-book

Comment: dseibert I found the second link useful. Just to clarify I meant by domain knowledge is the areas of knowledge that we are trying to model like stock control, invoicing, product numbering etc.. This will enable me to understand the concept behind modelling